# How do i create a function which returns a table/matrix in mathematica?

Tags: matrix, list-manipulation, conditional

I'm trying to create a matrix which will be of size 2N by 2N and have entries which will depend on the column and row number (u and v here). I'm sure this is a very trivial question but i'm really struggling to do this for some reason. Here's what I've attempted so far:

```
armchair_hamiltonian[N_, k_] := Table[
  if[Mod[u, 2] != 0 && v == (u + 1), -e^(-i*k/2), 0];
  if[Mod[u, 2] == 0 && v = (u - 1), -e^(i*k/2), 0];
  if[Mod[u + v - 1, 4] == 0 && Abs[u - v] < 4, -1, 0];
  {u, 2*N}, {v, 2*N}]

armchair_hamiltonian[5, 1];
MatrixForm[%];
```

Again sorry if this is trivial, I'm genuinely stumped as I'm very new to mathematica.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. The underscore character `_` represents `Blank`, a pattern matching construct. It cannot be used in a symbol name. Try `armchairHamiltonian`.

Comment: `N` is a protected symbol.  See [point 4](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18395/4999)

Comment: OP, if you want to separate words in your functions, you can use a `$` character in place of the `_`.

Answer (score 3):

You're not too far off;  you just need to use nested `If` functions rather than three successive commands:

```
armchairhamiltonian[n_, k_] := Table[
  If[Mod[u, 2] != 0 && v == (u + 1), -E^(-I*k/2), 
   If[Mod[u, 2] == 0 && v == (u - 1), -E^(I*k/2), 
    If[Mod[u + v - 1, 4] == 0 && Abs[u - v] < 4, -1, 0]]],
  {u, 2*n}, {v, 2*n}]

armchairhamiltonian[5, 1] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Also note the following syntax corrections that I made to your code above:

- Mathematica uses different commands for setting variables and for testing equality/inequality (`=` and `==` respectively.)  If you want something that returns `True` or `False` for an `If` statement, you must use `==` rather than `=`.  Your original code used `=` in one spot (probably just a typo.)
- The underscore character `_` is reserved for [pattern matching](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/Patterns.html) and cannot be used in variable names.  If you want to denote word boundaries in your variable names, I recommend [camel case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) (while always starting the first word in lowercase to avoid potential conflict with built-in functions.)
- The imaginary unit $i$ is `I` in Mathematica, not `i`;  and the base of natural logarithms $e$ is `E`, not `e`.  Given the mathematical expressions you're using, I suspect you mean `I` and `E`.
- `N` is a protected symbol;  it is the function that returns the numerical value of an expression.  (For example, Mathematica treats `Pi` as an exact number by default;  if you want its decimal expansion, use `N[Pi]` and you'll get 3.14159.)  Use `n` or `NN` or something like that instead.

Finally, for future reference:  it is often easier to construct such matrices using `SparseArray`.  This also can save memory and calculation time if the matrix is large.  In particular, the `Band` structure would be particularly helpful for constructing this matrix.